# Collapse rows based on a key in a csv file using awk or perl

Tags: awk, perl

**Input csv file :**

```
key,c1,c2,c3......,cn
1,car,phone,cat,.....,kite
2,abc,def,hij,.......,pot
1,yes,no,is,.........,hello
2,hello,yes,no,......,help
```

**Output csv file:**

```
Key,c1,c2,c3,.......,cn
1,caryes,phoneno,catis,.....,kitehello
2,abchello,defyes,hijno,....,pothelp
```

The input file has 14 million rows. Can someone help with an efficient way of doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are always exactly two lines with the same key and each line has n+1 elements?

Comment: No. It was just a sample. There could be 1000s of lines with the same key as there are about 14 million rows. There are 5550801 unique keys in the dataset. All the rows have the same number of columns, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how efficient it will be, but you could do something like this with a hash of anonymous arrays, using a `map` to apply the string concatenation assignment `.=` to each element of each hash value:

```
perl -F, -nle '
  $k = shift @F;
  map { $h{$k}[$_] .= $F[$_] } 0..$#F 
  }{ 
  for $k (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %h) {
    print join ",", $k, @{ $h{$k} }
  }' file
key,c1,c2,c3......,cn
1,caryes,phoneno,catis,..............,kitehello
2,abchello,defyes,hijno,.............,pothelp
```